# windows 8.1 store app crash when I open windows default setting flyout

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

When our custom windows 8.1 store app is crashed when I open windows 8.1 default setting flyout which access data from currently running app.

Comment: That's not enough information. If you create a new app and adding setting flyout is it working well?

Comment: this is custom application which is not require windows default feature like setting. when this custom app is in running mode If user drag mouse to top right corner in windows 8.1+  then it opens flyout which accesses current running applications information. If I click on Setting Icon right bottom of that flyout this custom application get crashed. like wise other application this flyout should open windows setting in place of my custom application setting.